# How do I resolve this error: "expected string or bytes-like object" please?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I was doing Lemmatisation but I got the above error. I think it's because my data isn't in string form, is that correct? If so, which part of my data isn't in string form?

[image: Image of code for Lemmatisation]
[image: Image of error code for Lemmatisation]

This is my data source: https://www.kaggle.com/c/fake-news/data

Answer (score 0):

You are applying that function to a column in a panda's dataframe. Double check the datatype of the column:

```py
lemmatised_df['label'].dtype
```